# Ubuntu equivalent of mkinitcpio.conf

Tags: initramfs, modprobe

I have a sh script that should be executed during system boot, as I understand before graphic driver modules are loaded.

Probably this is not relevant for the answer, but this script serves for PCI passthrough of a GPU in the special case a system has two identical GPUs sharing the same id, to override the driver assignment only on one of the two GPUs.

For arch linux systems, a wiki says that one should:

```
Edit /etc/mkinitcpio.conf:
Add modconf to the HOOKS array and /usr/local/bin/vfio-pci-override.sh 
to the FILES array.
Edit /etc/modprobe.d/vfio.conf:
Add the following line: install vfio-pci /usr/local/bin/vfio-pci-override.sh
Regenerate the initramfs and reboot.
```

What is the Ubuntu equivalent of mkinitcpio.conf and how should it be modified in this case?
Just in case, the script is the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

DEVS="0000:01:00.0 0000:01:00.1"

if [ ! -z "$(ls -A /sys/class/iommu)" ]; then
    for DEV in $DEVS; do
        echo "vfio-pci" > /sys/bus/pci/devices/$DEV/driver_override
    done
fi
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The package is called (man page) [initramfs-tools](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/initramfs-tools.8.html) (see wiki: [wiki.ubuntu.com/Initramfs](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Initramfs)).

> `initramfs-tools` - an introduction to writing scripts for mkinitramfs
>
> initramfs-tools  has  one  main  script and two different sets of subscripts which will be
>          used during different phases of execution. Each of  these  will  be  discussed  separately
>          below  with the help of an imaginary tool which performs a frobnication of a lvm partition
>          prior to mounting the root partition.

Configuration:

```
/etc/initramfs/initramfs.conf
```

Mind that ...

```
/etc/initramfs/conf.d/
```

can be used for configuration files and

```
/etc/initramfs/conf-hooks.d/
```

for adding hooks. To rebuild you can use ...

```
 update-initramfs -u
```

Comment: Thank you. My folder is /etc/initramfs-tools/ (on kubuntu 19.10) but besides that your answer was correct. I copied my script in /etc/initramfs/conf.d/  , rebuilded initramfs and rebooted. It did something: now one card has the usual kernel driver in use, the other has not. Unfortunately it did not bind vfio-pci to that GPU, but this might be another kind of problem.

Comment: Gratz on getting 1/2 working *O*

Comment: Can you be more specific. How to do the configurations and the hooks.